# how do i change table style when using render_template in Python Flask?

Tags: python, html, css, pandas

i'm making a website using flask, html and css, i use pandas to read a csv file, do some calculations and give me a table in my html. how can i change the style of the table? also how can i print the tables side by side?

here's the flask bit

```
@app.route('/')
def about():
    data = df[['attempts', 'activity']]
    data = data.groupby('activity').sum().sort_values('attempts', ascending=False).reset_index()

    datas = df[['grade', 'activity']]
    datas = datas.groupby('activity').sum().sort_values('grade', ascending=False).reset_index()
    return render_template("about.html", data=data.to_html(header='true'), data1=datas.to_html(header='true'),
```

here's the html bit:

```
    <section id="problems">
        <h2>problems</h2>
        <p class="lead">{{data | safe}} {{data1 |safe}}</p>
    </section>
```

Comment: Haven't you asked this exact question yesterday?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*how can i change the style of the table?*

If you are using [pandas.DataFrame.to_html](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html) it does accept *classes*, so if you have prepared CSS class say `mytable` then it should be enough to add `classes=["mytable"]` where you call `df.to_html` (where `df` is `pandas.DataFrame`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use css to customize the outcome of your html code. For example you‘ve created a css file you can refer the class „lead“ from the current code and change colors, margin and many more.
To get started take a look at what exactly you want to change and look how it will work with css/html. For tables you probably need to change your html and add a table and store your current html code in there, something like  for tabledata and  for table row and put the data you want to display in it.
I hope this get‘s you started, so you know where you can look it up!